# Cython "HelloWorld" example not running, but compiler?

Tags: python, gcc, mingw, cython

The cython "Hello World" example from http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/cython_tutorial.html
is not  running on my windows system, while  the compiler works

Any  hints are appreciated,  I try  to work  this out for days...

Here in more detail:

GCC seems to work on windows;  because  compiling  this C example worked:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (){
    printf("Hello world");
    return 0;

}
```

Now back to the Cython example:
it  worked  on Ubuntu,  but  throws the folowing error in windows:

```
Compiling helloworld.pyx because it changed.
[1/1] Cythonizing helloworld.pyx
running build_ext
building 'helloworld' extension
creating build
creating build\temp.win32-3.6
creating build\temp.win32-3.6\Release
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -mdll -O -Wall -DMS_WIN32 -IC:\Users\Tom\Anaconda3\include
-IC:\Users\Tom\Anaconda3\include -c helloworld.c -o build\temp.win32-3.6\Release
\helloworld.o
In file included from C:\Users\Tom\Anaconda3\include/Python.h:8:0,
                 from helloworld.c:16:
C:\Users\Tom\Anaconda3\include/pyconfig.h:68:0: Warnung: »MS_WIN32« redefiniert
 #define MS_WIN32 /* only support win32 and greater. */

<Kommandozeile>:0:0: Anmerkung: dies ist die Stelle der vorherigen Definition
In file included from C:\Users\Tom\Anaconda3\include/Python.h:65:0,
                 from helloworld.c:16:
C:\Users\Tom\Anaconda3\include/pytime.h:111:12: Warnung: »struct timeval« declar
ed inside parameter list will not be visible outside of this definition or decla
ration
     struct timeval *tv,
            ^~~~~~~
C:\Users\Tom\Anaconda3\include/pytime.h:116:12: Warnung: »struct timeval« declar
ed inside parameter list will not be visible outside of this definition or decla
ration
     struct timeval *tv,
            ^~~~~~~
writing build\temp.win32-3.6\Release\helloworld.cp36-win32.def
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -shared -s build\temp.win32-3.6\Release\helloworld.o build\
temp.win32-3.6\Release\helloworld.cp36-win32.def -LC:\Users\Tom\Anaconda3\libs -
LC:\Users\Tom\Anaconda3\PCbuild\win32 -lpython36 -lmsvcr140 -o "C:\Users\...\hw\helloworld.cp36-win32.pyd"
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot fin
d -lmsvcr140
collect2.exe: Fehler: ld gab 1 als Ende-Status zurück
error: command 'C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gcc.exe' failed with exit status 1
```

here the hello world code:

helloworld.pyx:

```
print("Hello World")
```

setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    ext_modules = cythonize("helloworld.pyx")
)
```

command:

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

Comment: The important error message says that the library `msvcr140` couldn't be found. The filename of the library is/should be probably `libmsvcr140.a`

Comment: thanks, but both files  can not be found ...

Comment: Which method did you use to convince distutils to use mingw? I think Cython recommends the one where you add a `compiler` entry in the `distutils.cfg` file, and the other one doesn't work right. ([The wiki](http://wiki.cython.org/InstallingOnWindows) seems to be down, so I'm going off memory here…)

Comment: Also, you're not mixing up 32-bit and 64-bit pieces, right?

Comment: Oops; I just have an ancient bookmark for the wiki; it's [on github nowadays](https://github.com/cython/cython/wiki/InstallingOnWindows).

Comment: in distutils.cfg  I have:[build]
compiler = mingw32